# Tiered list paragraph in Pages 5

Tags: pages

I have a document converted from pages 09 and I am trying to achieve with Pages 5 something that I was able to do easily with older version.

Basically I want a series of paragraphs structured like this, with no indentation, all aligned to left:

```
1.Title (h1)
text following...
1.1 title (h2)
text following...
1.1.1 title (h3)
text following...
1.1.2 title (h3)
text following...
```

I have three main header style header 1, header 2 and header 3, represented above as h1,2,3. I have assigned a numbered list to each of them, giving the correct checkbox option and the value from drop down selection that is translated from Italian: start from preceding.

However, I am not able to build such structure. Sometimes, I end up with this:

```
1.Title (h1)
text following...
1.1 title (h2)
text following...
2 title (h3)
text following...
3 title (h3)
text following...
```

Answer (score 1):

Simiply select  `Bullet & Numbering` style to be `Tiered Numbers` and it should work fine in iWork '09.

Comment: The question is about version 5 of Pages.